# TYPO3 Realurl Configuration Category Page

Tags: typo3, categories, realurl

I have TYPO3 7.6.10.
I have tx_news.

I want to configure my page with news by category.
Now i have:

```
'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
        'lookUpTable' => array(
            'table' => 'sys_category',
            'id_field' => 'uid',
            'alias_field' => 'title',
            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                'strtolower' => 1,
                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
            )
        )
    )
),
```

It works and the result is:

```
/domain/page-With-List-Of-News-By-Category/Category
```

If have a sub category the result is:

```
/domain/-page-With-List-Of-News-By-Category/Category
```

Ho can i get:

```
/domain/page-With-List-Of-News-By-Category/Parent-Category/Sub-Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a faster or better way. But if you won't find, try this and build it yourself using userfunc in that way:

```
'useUniqueCache_conf' => [
    'strtolower' => 1,
    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
    'encodeTitle_userProc' => 'My\Ext\Hooks\News\RealUrlCategories->buildCategoryPath'
];
```

and the class something like:

```
class RealUrlCategories {
    function buildCategoryPath($parameters) {

        $categoriesPath = '';

        // find category rootline
        // you can find the uid somewhere in $parameters, then iterate for parent categories and read db for the titles to build final string

        ...

        // return generated string like "Parent-Category/Sub-Category"
        return $categoriesPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: No effect at all, or not working as expected? Make sure the userfunc is called. Clear autoload caches.

Comment: No effect at all. Version of realurl is: 2.0.14 . i clearead all caches.

Comment: ho check if userfunc is called?

Comment: Put some die('is called!'); inside, or something like that. It should break script execution. If nothing happens, it's not called. Make sure about namespace and correct script location, that the autoload could find it.

Comment: i put die('is called') before 'class RealUrlCategories' and nothing happens :(

Comment: What namespace you use and where did you put the class file?

Comment: Thank you for your patience.

In realconf.php i added: `encodeTitle_userProc' => 'MyVendor/MyExtension/Hooks/News/RealUrlCategories->buildCategoryPath`

In RealUrlCategories.php the namespace is: `MyVendor\MyExtension\Hooks\News`

Directory path is: `myextension/Hooks/News`

Comment: You must configure userfunc namespace call using backslashes like this:
`'encodeTitle_userProc' => 'MyVendor\MyExtension\Hooks\News\RealUrlCategories->buildCategoryPath'`

And the class file must be in typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Classes/Hooks/News/
(you missed the Classes dir, and note the namespace case: MyVendor\MyExtension if the ext dir is "my_extension", or MyVendor\Myextension, if the ext dir is "myextension".
Please refer to this doc for details:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/7.6/ApiOverview/Namespaces/

Comment: I also tried `'strtolower' =>0 ', spaceCharacter' => '_'` but nothing happens. it seems useUniqueCache_conf is ignored

Comment: I set `'useUniqueCache' => 0` and take effects

Comment: I made some progress!
The function now works. 
So I tried to return `$params['processedTitle']` like "myword/mycategory".
I see in the table "tx_realurl_uniqalias" the correct alias "myword/mycategory" but the link generated is "myword%252Fmycategory".
If i try the url "myword/mycategory" typo3 show the error 'Reason: Segment "myword/mycategory"  was not a keyword for a postVarSet as expected on page with id=160.'

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that realURL parses the result of the userFunc with rawurlencode. So `Parent-Category/Sub-Category` would be transformed to `Parent-Category%252FSub-Category`.

1. You could return `Parent-Category-Sub-Category`. This would also be stored in the cache.
2. Also your UserFunc could return Parent-Category~~~Sub-Category and you replace the ~~~ with a `/` in a `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['encodeSpURL_postProc']` hook, but the ~~~ will be stored in the cache.
3. You could also add another parameter like `parent_category`, but this optional parameter doesn't work in the `fixesPostVars` section because here the parameter is required and so if it is empty, you have an double slash //category in your URL.

Could you find any other solution beside to use the format parent-category-sub-category?